# How to return data from selenium to calling function in python

Tags: python, django, selenium, nose

I am running a a selenium functional test using nose from inside a django function using:

```
arg = sys.argv[:1]
arg.append('--verbosity=2')
arg.append('-v')
out = nose.run(module=ft1.testy1, argv=arg, exit=False)
```

I have created the functional test using the selenium IDE. Part of the test looks like:

```
class y1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.yahoo.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_y1(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Weather").click()
        driver.save_screenshot('out1.png')
        return " this is a returned value"
```

I want to return a string value (" this is a returned value") to the calling function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your `nose.run()` does not correspond to your test method. The default behavior for `unittest.TestCase` is to throw an exception. If you would like to signal an external code some specific detail, you can always do it through global/class variables, files, etc.

For example, this is how to do it with a class variable (`results`)

**ft1_runner.py:**

```
import nose

import ft1_test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    out = nose.run(module=ft1_test, exit=False)
    print 'Y1.test_y1 test results returned:', ft1_test.Y1.results['test_y1']
```

**ft1_test.py:**

```
import unittest

class Y1(unittest.TestCase):
    results = {}

    def test_y1(self):
        Y1.results['test_y1'] = "this is a returned value"
```

I think it would help if you can describe the problem you are trying to solve: this seems a little awkward and error prone (what if the test is called twice, or test skipped, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Oleksiy. I'm pretty new to python so could I ask for more detail on how you would do this, Lets say I want to make the string " this is a returned value" available to the calling function.

Comment: added a code example, but it would be helpful to see the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I assume "results = {}" would be a global variable?

Comment: Yes, anyone referring to Y1 class will be able to see the `results.`